# Template not found when i run python manage.py runserver on pydriod 3 app

Tags: python, django, pydroid

I've been trying to create a blog with django using my phone and so far until yesterday it has been a success. I was creating my home page yesterday and when I run python manage.py runserver it returns a template not found error. What can be the issue?

This is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def home(request):
 
       returnrender(request,'newfile.html')
```

This is my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    
    path('', views.home, name="homepage"),

]
```

This is my `settings.py`

```
"""

Django settings for myproject project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.7.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""


import os


from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-@o12m78t3=13)@m-o^-ejlp@g!-0gz64fiwx%+raw753+=g2)r'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = 

[

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [


    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',


]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

TEMPLATES = [


    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,  'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },


]
```

I made sure to avoid any spelling errors or indentation errors. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

First you should not post your secret key here.

Than you do have a a spelling error in def home(request):

```
returnrender(request,'newfile.html')
```

If thats correct on your local project:

What is the path to your templatefile ?
It should be: myapp/template/myapp/home.html